# jquery ajax next page won't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have `index.html` where there is `nav menu`, `header`, `footer` and `div.content` where jQuery parses html of `page1.html`.

`page1.html` loads fine, but when I add function to `.nextPage2` to load `page2.html`, it wont work.

`page1.html` does not have `head`, `body` and  `script`.

```js
$( document ).ready(()=> {
//Ajax
$.ajax({
  url: 'page1.html',
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(result){
  $('.content').html(result);
}});

$(".nextPage2").click(()=>{
  $(".content").html("");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'page2.html',
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(result){
    $('.content').html(result);
  }});
})

//Ajax
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navMenu">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li class="page1">page</li>
        <li class="page2">page</li>
        <li class="page3">page</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>



  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<!--page1.html
<section class="page1">
  Bunch of code without head, script, body etc
  <button type="button" class="nextPage2" name="button">page2</button>
</section>

-->
```

Comment: please show us your HTML for the menu. We have no way to know if you've set this up correctly or not. Also are you by any chance replacing all the menu as well as the main content whenever you load the files by ajax? That would cause the HTML elements to be replaced, and the jQuery events are not automatically bound to their replacements.

Comment: @ADyson Post edited. Im only ajaxing content into div .content

Comment: If your `".nextPage2"` is loaded dynamically, then you need `$(document).on('click', ".nextPage2", () =>)` as you can't bind events on dynamic elements

Comment: can you show the full implementation of your work

Comment: use justinas logic to solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like **@Justinas** said, you need http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on("click",".nextPage2",()=>{
  $(".content").html("");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'page2.html',
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(result){
    $('.content').html(result);
  }});
})
```

Comment: correct but it would help everyone if you explained _why_ this is necessary

Comment: Just read the question, thats **WHY**

Comment: @Justinas explained *If your ".nextPage2" is loaded dynamically, then you need $(document).on('click', ".nextPage2", () =>) as you can't bind events on dynamic elements*

Comment: I don't think that really explains it fully tbh. And "can't bind on dynamic elements" isn't true...you can, but you have to use ".on" in a certain way. The explanation should be _why_ you have to use .on() and also explain the syntax - the significance of binding to a higher-level element such as `document`, and why the real selector is passed as an argument. Perhaps you could quote from the docs you linked to, it has a section about delegated events. (And besides, don't rely on other people's comments - add the explanation into your answer, so it's a complete answer by itself.)

Comment: TBF though, the marked duplicate kind of explains it already, so maybe you needn't bother.